# [Not A Type release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x5853f00

Tags: iphone, ios

[Not A Type release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x5853f00 getting this error please help when adding a view

```
AnotherView* obj = [[AnotherView alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:obj.view];
[obj release];
```

Comment: is your AnotherView is a subclass of UIViewController or UIView ?

Comment: If it is a UIView then **[self.view addSubview:obj]** is enough

Comment: it's subclass of EAGLView which is subclass of @interface EAGLView : UIView {

Comment: and what is your EAGLView class type?

Answer (score 1):

You are adding [UIView view] to the current view. There is no view property inside UIView.

As pointed out, you should add the UIView object itself.

In an OpenGL context, you should also consider what the docs say:

> Note: If you are using OpenGL ES to do your drawing, your view’s drawRect: method is not called. Instead, it is up to you to determine when your view needs to be redrawn and initiate the appropriate drawing updates.

So make sure your UIVIew is initialized correctly.

Comment: Thanks a lot.But i m not good in open gl programming please tell me how can i do that or any sample code

Answer (score 1):

You generally get this error when you send a message to already released instance. So what I suspect in your code is, you created some views and then you added it to some other view and released the previous created view. Now if any action performed on the first view (which is already released) will cause the exception.
i.e.: First View contains a button and action for this button's touchup inside is written in FristViewController. Now I created the instance of FirstView and added into second view and released the firstview instance. Now suppose user tap on FirstView's button then, iOS will search for controller (FirstViewController) which is already released, and this problem will occur.
To get rid of the problem you can simply send autorelease message to the instance and will work fine.

The main reason of this happening is, addSubview does not take care of retain count.
I hope this will help you.

Comment: AddSubview does retain the count - View param: `The view to be added. This view is retained by the receiver. After being added, this view appears on top of any other subviews.`

Comment: Do one thing. Create a sample application and execute whatsoever I described and then you will see it. It may not crash immediately (because release message is an indication, but not the force to release). But once it will be released by iOS and you will call the action implemented in it, you will (surely) face this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can't release  obj because [self.view addSubview:obj.view] only add view of obj not entire object.
If you release it and your view is visible on screen then it may possible that some message will be sent to deallocated object, so it result in crash.

Comment: i follow what u say but getting this error now               NSInvocation: warning: object 0x4b962d0 of class '_NSZombie_Not A Type' does not implement doesNotRecognizeSelector: -- abort

Comment: remove [obj release] line and if you still get then there might be some other issue.